# Is it possible to update a VS deployed app without changing app's URL?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm building a SharePoint hosted app which for now I'm deploying from VS. Every time I redeploy the changes, it completely reinstalls the app also changing its URL (the unique identifier part of it) which means I also need to change IIS bindings (my dev box doesn't have a DNS server) and some client side code every time as well.

Is there any way to update the app without changing its URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is generated when you deploy the App, so it's not something you can control. But what you can do is to test your stuff while you are in debug mode. So you hit the F5 and launch your app, whenever you do the change you just save it in VS and refresh the page in your app. Would that solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it tomorrow. DO you know by any chance if there is a workaround for having to set IIS binding for the app?

Comment: I don't think you could do so, because it's auto generated, so you would not expect the generated ID.